# How to get the Polkadot address from the polkadot public key? Polkadot.js

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I tried `@polkadot/util-crypto` lib and `@polkadot/keyring` to convert, public key to polkadot address but no help.

Is there any method provided by the `polkadot.js`?

Steps on how to get the address will also work great.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@polkadot/util-crypto` exposes the function `encodeAddress` which can input your public key bytes/hex and output an SS58 encoded address. If you want to get the address for a specific network, like Polkadot, you need to provide a secondary parameter which is the SS58 Prefix for that network. In the case of Polkadot it is 0.

https://docs.substrate.io/reference/address-formats/#address-type

For example:

```js
let address = util_crypto.encodeAddress("0x263158a10b39debac59bd1239bc64fb4bd678f507814d24f59efd46279111c71", 0)

document.getElementById("output").innerText = address;
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/polkadot-js-bundle/polkadot.js"></script>

<div id="output"></output>
```